# node-telegram-bot-api: CHAT_ADMIN_REQUIRED

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Hi I am trying to revoke an invite link  but when I am providing chat_id and invite_link but still throwing an error `Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: CHAT_ADMIN_REQUIRED`

Here is the code which I used to revoke invite link
`bot.revokeChatInviteLink(chat_id, "https://t.me/joinchat/some_key")`

Answer (score 0):

Your bot needs **Admin Rights**!

From the  [`revokechatinvitelink`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#revokechatinvitelink) documentation:

> ***revokeChatInviteLink***
>
> Use this method to revoke an invite link created by the bot. If the primary link is revoked, a new link is automatically generated. **The bot must be an administrator in the chat for this to work and must have the appropriate admin rights.** Returns the revoked invite link as [ChatInviteLink](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatinvitelink) object.

---

- Make your bot admin of the chat
- Add the necessary rights

Comment: Actually I have made the bot as admin of the group. I think here I am making mistake that I have two bots and one of them is creating the invite_link and other one is revoking it. Is it something which is causing I am not sure. Bt I need two bots for these two task. Because when I was doing all this with one bot it was throwing error saying that `2 instance of same bot can not be created`.

Comment: A bot can only revoke a invite link created by the bot iteself. Another bot wont be able to revoke it.